# How do I check my played time?

Tags: eve-online

Is there a way to check my total game time in Eve?

For example, in WoW if you type [/played](http://www.wowwiki.com/MACRO_played) in the chat, it displays time played for your current character. Is there a similar thing in Eve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [EVE Api Key Management](https://community.eveonline.com/support/api-key/), and click the **create new apy key** button

Set the name as "Played time", choose your character and select **Account Status** in the Private Information menu, as in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

After this, you will have a Key ID (keyID), and a Verification Code(vCode):

[image]

You will have to use this generated keyID and vCode in the following URL, and then open it in a browser:

> `https://api.eveonline.com/account/AccountStatus.xml.aspx?keyID=KEYID&vCode=VERIFICATIONCODE`

For example:

> `https://api.eveonline.com/account/AccountStatus.xml.aspx?keyID=3020301&vCode=JZRN9JUVKuU3t41K3ED0HpZoIHjlmIkVHMUhpJsuajND18l0PtRwEDyzNxX2Rkzf`

Then finally you can check your logon minutes in the following XML tag, and just do the math:

> `<logonMinutes>1631</logonMinutes>`

Answer (score 2):

Start LogServer.exe (Found in EVE Directory)
Ctrl-W to start a new workspace
Start EVE Online
Log into your main

Go to LogServer
Ctrl-F, enter "logonminutes" and change Directions to up
You'll find 1 entry containing this string and it'll be the only one with this entry.
Look 5-6 lines below it and you'll come across an entry that contains "charUnboundMgr::GetCharacterToSelect"
Right below that one contains your play time, it'll look like "10000002, False, 246777, None"
The 10000002 is the current region that the character is located in (10000002 is The Forge), followed by a false/true and then the next number is your total play time in minutes.

Source: [Eve Forums](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=539352)

Comment: I could not get the played time with this approach.